# How do I interpret the confidence score of my model?

Tags: swift, coreml

I have this code here:

```
let classifications = request.results as! [VNClassificationObservation]
let firstDetected = String(classifications[0].identifier)
let firstConfidence = String(classifications[0].confidence)
```

and while firstDetected returns the value I am looking for, firstConfidence returns:

```
"4.7720193e-25"
```

I was hoping to instead get a percentage confidence value. I am using loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' and sigmoid as the last layer. How would I achieve this using Swift?

EDIT

Outout when I printed all confidences (34 classes)

```
2.3669429411067955e-22
1.875580037253118e-22
6.712531669584665e-23
1.4298457316816378e-23
1.3310861839186658e-23
7.145695350413704e-24
6.4237113117241614e-24
6.101622953996496e-24
5.920554921560212e-24
5.268301453726775e-24
4.8217758102268314e-24
3.844093553162571e-24
2.955565200162768e-24
2.6157801285330532e-24
2.178856697186686e-24
1.9371907365940395e-24
1.4362409875972193e-24
4.7065206681761e-25
3.3442027513233967e-25
2.5342553475867944e-25
2.3227792417483757e-25
9.117256830603933e-26
1.2949678693635693e-26
6.908813763418489e-27
5.3868329877988985e-27
2.2091837798420553e-27
5.343971705776052e-28
3.136374025539697e-28
1.8983565257440653e-28
1.0716665045553994e-28
4.809785544897979e-29
8.263390505489567e-31
2.4524197581883286e-31
7.953158503299082e-32
```

Comment: That _is_ a percentage, just very very low. Which is a little weird because the first result should be the one which the highest confidence. What happens if you print out the confidences of the other results?

Comment: edited my question to show output

Comment: Ah, I missed that you used sigmoid as output in your model. I don't think you can use `VNClassificationObservation` with such a model because Core ML / Vision's classification model expects there to be a softmax (multiclass) while you're doing multi-label. In any case, what you're seeing is that the negative class is being predicted for all your examples. Whether this makes sense or not depends on what your Core ML model actually looks like.